# Display Chef Minitest Handler Test Results In Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, chef-infra, vagrant, minitest

I am trying to test my chef cookbooks in VM using chef-minitest-handler and Vagrant. I am able to run the tests, but I want to integrate it into Jenkins.

Is there any possibility to save tests' results obtained from chef [converge in VM] in a way that Jenkins will understand (jUnit for example) and show a nice passed/failed tests graph?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the git version of chef-minitest-handler (at least) there is a handler parameter called :ci_reports which specifies where you want the junit output stored.  For example:

```
handler = MiniTest::Chef::Handler.new({
:path    => './cookbooks/test/*_test.rb',
:ci_reports => 'report.xml',
:verbose => true})
# add to the list of handlers
```

This will write a junit compatible report to report.xml

Comment: Ahhahaah. Nice one! They added it on July 11 :). I was too impatient.